# Is clang able to replace Exuberant Ctags?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, exuberant-ctags

To investigate new files I'm used to run `ctags` with the appropriate options, the problem is that apparently this program doesn't support C++11 and I was just using it fine until I discovered that the development of this program ended years ago .

Now I need an equivalent tool for C++11 and beyond, and I remember that `clang` alone is able to output the `AST` of any given file so I was wondering if the fronted had similar functionalities that were comparable to what I used to do with `ctags` .

For example this are the entities that you can easily list with `ctags` in C++ mode

```
ctags --list-kinds=c++
c  classes
d  macro definitions
e  enumerators (values inside an enumeration)
f  function definitions
g  enumeration names
l  local variables [off]
m  class, struct, and union members
n  namespaces
p  function prototypes [off]
s  structure names
t  typedefs
u  union names
v  variable definitions
x  external and forward variable declarations [off]
```

Does `clang` is able to perform a similar task ?

Comment: What C++11 feature does exuberant ctags not support that you need?  While there hasn't been a ctags release for a while, development/support is stil ongoing -- the latest change in [the offical SourceForge tree](http://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/code/HEAD/tree/) was only a week ago.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I tried to list some functions and classes in a mostly templated source file and it showed nothing . The last update on the official website is from 2009 tho . Following your comment I checked with `ctags --version` and my build is based on the svn trunk, so I must be doing something wrong, probably it doesn't support templates ? I'm not sure what can possibly be wrong here .

Comment: **Update 2016:** There is another project [`universal-ctags`](https://ctags.io/) which says to continue the development of exuberant-ctags on github. In the context of this question see in particular the new [`c/c++` parser](http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/parser-cxx.html).

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) tool. It uses clang to recompile your entire project.
After that you can use it to navigate through the sources. The only problem is
that AST is built after preprocessor has run, so the code that was disabled by
macros is not available for navigation.

The projects maintains a set of elisp bindings that allows you to control `RTags` from emacs. For integration in vim see the third-party projects by [lyuts](https://github.com/lyuts/vim-rtags) or [Shane Harper](https://github.com/shaneharper/vim-rtags).

Comment: Linux/OSX only.

Answer (score 0):

The llvm/clang project does not include a tool to generate tag files from the ast. However, there are several projects on github using clang to do this, which can be found via: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=clang+tags

Following two projects got some attention (stars, issues, pull requests)

- http://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/ (last commit: Jan 4, 2014)
- https://github.com/drothlis/clang-ctags (last commit: Jun 18, 2014)
  (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ExternalClangExamples.html points to this project)
- (rtags, see answer by [Nikolai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26975369/1057593))

Unfortunately, there are no recent commits, however, the authors still respond to raised issues.

*Disclaimer* I know link-only answers are discouraged. I will extend this question when I find the time to test the projects and see how they compare to *Exuberant-ctags* or *Universal-ctags*.